# Golang Memory Leak Concerning Goroutines

Tags: multithreading, memory-leaks, go, goroutine

I have a Go program that runs continuously and relies entirely on goroutines + 1 `manager` thread. The main thread simply calls goroutines and otherwise sleeps.

There is a memory leak. The program uses more and more memory until it drains all 16GB RAM + 32GB SWAP and then each goroutine panics. It is actually OS memory that causes the panic, usually the panic is `fork/exec ./anotherapp: cannot allocate memory` when I try to execute `anotherapp`.

When this happens all of the worker threads will panic and be recovered and restarted. So each goroutine will panic, be recovered and restarted... at which point the memory usage will not decrease, it remains at 48GB even though there is now virtually nothing allocated. This means all goroutines will always panic as there is never enough memory, until the entire executable is killed and restarted completely.

The entire thing is about 50,000 lines, but the actual problematic area is as follows:

```
type queue struct {
    identifier string
    type bool
}

func main() {

    // Set number of gorountines that can be run
    var xthreads int32 = 10
    var usedthreads int32
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(14)
    ready := make(chan *queue, 5)

    // Start the manager goroutine, which prepared identifiers in the background ready for processing, always with 5 waiting to go
    go manager(ready)

    // Start creating goroutines to process as they are ready
    for obj := range ready { // loops through "ready" channel and waits when there is nothing

        // This section uses atomic instead of a blocking channel in an earlier attempt to stop the memory leak, but it didn't work
        for atomic.LoadInt32(&usedthreads) >= xthreads {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
        debug.FreeOSMemory() // Try to clean up the memory, also did not stop the leak
        atomic.AddInt32(&usedthreads, 1) // Mark goroutine as started

        // Unleak obj, probably unnecessary, but just to be safe
        copy := new(queue)
        copy.identifier = unleak.String(obj.identifier) // unleak is a 3rd party package that makes a copy of the string
        copy.type = obj.type
        go runit(copy, &usedthreads) // Start the processing thread

    }

    fmt.Println(`END`) // This should never happen as the channels are never closed
}

func manager(ready chan *queue) {
    // This thread communicates with another server and fills the "ready" channel
}

// This is the goroutine
func runit(obj *queue, threadcount *int32) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            // Panicked
            erstring := fmt.Sprint(r)
            reportFatal(obj.identifier, erstring)
        } else {
            // Completed successfully
            reportDone(obj.identifier)
        }
        atomic.AddInt32(threadcount, -1) // Mark goroutine as finished
    }()
    do(obj) // This function does the actual processing
}
```

As far as I can see, when the `do` function (last line) ends, either by having finished or having panicked, the `runit` function then ends, which ends the goroutine entirely, which means all of the memory from that goroutine should now be free. This is now what happens. What happens is that this app just uses more and more and more memory until it becomes unable to function, all the `runit` goroutines panic, and yet the memory does not decrease.

Profiling does not reveal anything suspicious. The leak appears to be outside of the profiler's scope.

Comment: I would try the code you posted _without_ the code you haven't posted. Use a `manager()` function which just generates input endlessly and a `do()` function which does nothing (empty function). See if you still have a memory leak. If not, then obviously the leak is in the code you haven't posted in which case there's nothing we can do in the current state of the question.

Comment: Are you using unsafe or C anywhere? Latest Go version? I would try to run it with GODEBUG=gctrace=1 to check what is going on with the garbage collector.

Comment: Could be, somehow, it's leaking goroutines: something never gets to exit.  There are old statements from mailing lists that goroutine stacks are never returned to the system. `goroutineCount, _ := runtime.GoroutineProfile(nil)` can quickly tell you how many are running.

Comment: ThunderCat's comment is spot on.  The code you're trying to use to limit the number of working threads looks low-level and frankly error-prone.  You most likely want to take the approach in: http://talks.golang.org/2012/waza.slide#41, where you limit the number of worker goroutines, which pull from a shared channel of work.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed from atomic to a fixed number of goroutines that are reused. Ironic actually because I avoided that specifically thinking it would increase memory usage. It'll take a couple of days to see the results. Still this must represent a bug in the compiler, no? (Assuming this fixes it.)

Comment: So the problem is worse now that goroutines are reused rather than destroyed. So that points to a memory leak unrelated to the goroutines but it must be a package using C or unsafe. I will investigate all such packages.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider inverting the pattern, see [here](https://play.golang.org/p/CJ8-Z8W3GL) or below....

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// I do work
func worker(id int, work chan int) {
    for i := range work {
        // Work simulation
        log.Printf("Worker %d, sleeping for %d seconds\n", id, i)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(i)) * time.Second)
    }
}

// Return some fake work
func getWork() int {
    return rand.Intn(2) + 1
}

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    work := make(chan int)

    // run 10 workers
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            worker(i, work)
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    // main "thread"
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        work <- getWork()
    }

    // signal there is no more work to be done
    close(work)

    // Wait for the workers to exit
    wg.Wait()
}
```